# pass context to callable

Tags: java, android, callable

I am creating several tasks to download some files from the internet and I want to access the context in MyTasks.class . What is the best way?

```
public class MyTasks {

    public Callable<File> DownloadImage(String url) {

        return new Callable<File>() {
            @Override
            public File call() throws Exception {

                File imageFile = new File(- context here - .getExternalFilesDir(null) , "example.png");


                // download task here


                return imageFile;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I pass context via constructor will it cause memory leak or any other problems ?

Comment: In your code, you do not need the `Context`. The result of `getExternalFilesDir(null)` is what you need, which is just a `File`. If you are sure that you need a `Context`, call `getApplication()` on some other `Context` to get the `Application` singleton for your process, as `Application` is a `Context`, and as a singleton it cannot be leaked further by your code.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi. Without context, can't get access to getExternalFilesDir(null) - Cannot resolve method

Comment: If you know a number of files, you can create files and pass a list of files. You can delete any of them later. This class can cause memory leak if called from a short-living object like Fragment.

Comment: "Without context, can't get access to getExternalFilesDir(null)" -- you would call that *outside* of `DownloadImage` and pass the result into the `DownloadImage` constructor, the way that you are passing in `url`.

Comment: @CoolMind You are right. I call this class from a fragment, which is what prompted me to ask

Comment: @CommonsWare I got it, do you think there will be a memory leak ?  because I'm calling it from fragment

Comment: `File` will not leak memory.